# How do I tell AngularJS that I've been cheating on it with jQuery?

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I'm hacking together an admin interface using a pre-fab template. The navigation system that is already built uses jQuery to load content into a tag via AJAX based on `window.location.hash`.

If I fetch this snipped via an AJAX call and then insert it into the DOM:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    {{ 2 + 2 }}
</div>
```

AngularJS has no idea that I've updated the DOM. The content that I see is, literally, `{{ 2 + 2 }}`. If I reload the page, the expression evaluates and I see the value `4` that I desire.

How do I ask AngularJS to please evaluate the content that I so brutally forced upon the DOM via non-Angularian methods?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4zRTH/

**EDIT**

The answer from @tasseKATT works great for simple expressions, but I'm having trouble accessing a controller. I have a `NotesController` that the code that I'm importing needs to access. Something more along the lines of:

```
<div ng-controller="NotesController">
    {{ notes.length }}
</div>
```

I updated the fiddle so it's a little more along the lines of what I'm looking to do: http://jsfiddle.net/5Xhs9/4/

Comment: Assuming your jQuery DOM modification is handled in an Angular directive, have you tried calling $scope.$apply() at the end of your response handler?

Comment: I'm not using an Angular directive for DOM modification. The navigation system was pre-built on jQuery alone.

Comment: Sounds pretty hacky, but maybe you could trigger a jQuery event and listen for it inside your directive/controller and call $scope.$apply() in the handler?

Comment: $scope.$apply will only work for compiled directives. If new html is appended, angular will ignore until it compiled. What OP needs is $compile service, as stated in @musically_ut answer.

Comment: You donot need to compile or anything. Just bootstrap angular only after all jquery dynamic html is loaded. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QC97L/2/ for a simple answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `$apply`:

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.

In your example however the app is not even bootstrapped, so you need to:

1) Select the element:

```
var dynamicContent = "<div id='someId' ng-app> {{ 2 + 2 }} </div>";
$('.expression').html(dynamicContent);

var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#someId'));
```

2) Bootstrap it:

```
angular.bootstrap(element, []);
```

3) Retrieve the scope:

```
var elementScope = element.scope();
```

4) Call $apply:

```
elementScope.$apply();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5Xhs9/

**Edit for new scenario:**

In your new example you have added `ng-app"myApp"` to an existing div, so AngularJS will bootstrap your application for you, and now you want to dynamically add this content instead:

```
<div id='notes' ng-controller='NotesController'> {{ notes.length }} </div>
```

You have already defined the `NotesController` and added it to the module. What you now can do is:

1) Retrieve the `$injector` service:

```
var $injector = angular.element(document.querySelector('.container')).injector();
```

2) Use the `$injector` to compile the newly added element and link it to its `scope`. Call `$apply`:

```
var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#notes'));

$injector.invoke(function($compile) {
  var scope = element.scope();
  $compile(element)(scope);
  scope.$apply();
});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/P6VwLee6AUWO7aDT601m?p=preview

Comment: That works for simple expressions, thanks! If I try to to import something that is bound to a controller, I get an `[ng:areq]` Controller not a function, undefined error. Do I need to change the arguments to angular.boostrap() maybe?

Comment: I added an update to my answer to fit your new scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You can *cheat* by saving `$compile` and `$rootScope` in the `app.run` function on `window`: http://plnkr.co/edit/pxGhof1zD0rZknagfmyc?p=preview

```js
window.compileForAngular = null;
window.rootScope = null;

var app = angular.module('jQuery', []);
app.run(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    window.rootScope = $rootScope;
    window.compileForAngular = $compile;
    doNotTryThisAtHome();
});

function doNotTryThisAtHome() {
    // let's just pretend that this came in over an AJAX request
var dynamicContent = "<div> {{ 2 + 2 }} </div>";

// I insert it into the DOM via jQuery
$('.expression').html(window.compileForAngular(dynamicContent)(window.rootScope));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/QC97L/2/

See the above fiddle

```
// Code goes here
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
// let's just pretend that this came in over an AJAX request
var dynamicContent = "<div id='mainApp' > {{ 2 + 2 }}  </div>";

// I insert it into the DOM via jQuery
$('.expression').html(dynamicContent);





  var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
   angular.bootstrap('#mainApp',['myApp']);

// now how do I get AngularJS to evalulate the expression?

});
```