# How do I tell AngularJS to evaluate the expressions in the results of an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

Consider this snippet of code taken from the AngularJS tutorial:

```
<div ng-app="phonecatApp">
    <div ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
                {{phone.name}}
                <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

    var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

    phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.phones = [
            {'name': 'Nexus S',
                'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
            {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
                'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
            {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
                'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
        ];
    });

</script>
```

If I paste this code in the `body` an `html` document (with AngularJS, of course) and load the page, the expressions evaluate properly.

However, if I place the above code into a separate file and load it dynamically using AJAX and then insert it into the `body` tag, the expressions don't evaluate.

How can I get the expressions to evaluate if I load the above code via AJAX?

Comment: Could you create a plnkr or jsfiddle to show what you have done? Are you certain that the data coming from your AJAX source is formatted the same way as your code sample?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891723/how-do-i-tell-angularjs-that-ive-been-cheating-on-it-with-jquery